# format rest Api group field by category

Tags: php, mysql, api, rest, codeigniter

I am new to API  I used Codeigniter to create an APi from a MySql Databse Products which have 
the field : Amount , quantity, customerName, CustomerPhone, CustomerAddress
the rsult looks:

````
```[
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Amount": "21542",
        "quantity": "52",
        "customerName": "John",
        "CustomerPhone": "254215",
        "CustomerAddress": "road tvz120",

    },```
````

but i want it to look this way:

````
```[
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Amount": "21542",
        "quantity": "52",
        "customerInfo":{
        "customerName": "John",
        "CustomerPhone": "254215",
        "CustomerAddress": "rue tvz120"},

    },```
````

I mean to group the 3 field concernign customers with the name customer info

my php code is

````
```public function index_get($id = 0)
    {
        if(!empty($id)){
            $data = $this->db->get_where("Products", ['Id' => $id])->row_array();
        }else{
            $data = $this->db->get("Products")->result();
        }

        $this->response($data, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Products format is based on database, therefore if you want to change the result format, you have to construct it manually. You need to loop the result before returning the data.

```
if(!empty($id)){
    $data = $this->db->get_where("Products", ['Id' => $id])->row_array();
}else{
    $data = $this->db->get("Products")->result();
    $newdata = array();

    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        $newdata[] = array(
            "Id" => $row->id,
            "Amount" => $row->amount,
            "quantity" => $row->quantity,
            "customerInfo" => array(
                "customerName" => $row->customerName,
                "CustomerPhone" => $row->CustomerPhone,
                "CustomerAddress" => $row->CustomerAddress,
            )
        );
    }
    $data = $newdata;
}
$this->response($data, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot perform this via query, you'll have to loop through the result and change it to the desired format, like so -

```
if(!empty($id)){

    $result = $this->db->get_where("Products", ['Id' => $id])->result(); 
    // I'll advise to use result() here instead of row_array() so that you don't face any issue when there's only one row.

}else{

    $result = $this->db->get("Products")->result();

}

foreach($result as $res){

    $new_result[] = array(
        "Id"           => $res->Id,
        "Amount"       => $res->Amount,
        "quantity"     => $res->quantity,
        "customerInfo" => array(
                                "customerName"    => $res->customerName,
                                "CustomerPhone"   => $res->CustomerPhone,
                                "CustomerAddress" => $res->CustomerAddress
                                )
                    );
}
$this->response($new_result, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK); // send newly created array instead
```

See if this helps you.